# Custom advanced filtering

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using Wordpress to build a reasonably complex query builder and I am fairly close to completing it, I am essentially building up a large query based on the users options which looks something like the following:

```
(SELECT x_posts.* FROM x_posts LEFT JOIN x_term_relationships 
ON (x_posts.ID = x_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 
AND (x_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (13) ) 
AND x_posts.post_type = 'articles' GROUP BY x_posts.ID ORDER BY x_posts.post_date DESC )
UNION
(SELECT * FROM x_posts where post_type = 'articles'
AND post_title LIKE '%he%' )
```

This gives me back a full response set that I intend on sorting through using PHP based on the users inputs. So far, the user has built up the result set but then further drill downs are required.

I cannot for the life of me work out how to join the Taxonomies / meta back into this thus allowing me to use php to filter the array returned form the DB.

Is there a way of appending / concatenating a join into the above query? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND 
wm.`meta_key`='repeatable_fields')
INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` wtr ON (wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`)
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` wtt ON (wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = 
wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`)
INNER JOIN `wp_terms` wt ON (wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`)
AND wtt.taxonomy = 'location' AND wt.`slug`IN ('berlin','canada')
AND wp.post_status = 'publish' AND wm.meta_value LIKE '%July%' 
ORDER BY wp.post_date DESC
```

The initial query can have multiple unions and be quite complicated. I am able to do all of the filtering via PHP.

Sorry if I am missing something, I haven't had to do this kinda crazy stuff with WordPress before.

Thank you,

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're further from completion than you seem to think :-(

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)